# How to see all possible scaling resolutions in System Preferences > Displays? (Holding down Option no longer works in Big Sur)

Tags: macos, display, big-sur, resolution, system-settings

On my MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020) running Big Sur 11.5.x, holding down the Option key while selecting *Scaled* in *System Preferences* > *Displays* > *Display* (tab) > *Resolution* no longer has any effect. In the past, that trick changed the four icons of resolution size to a list of all possible resolutions, with many more than four choices.

Is there some way to access that list of all possible resolutions in Big Sur?

Comment: I've been looking over other sites and it looks like you may have to use an app like SwitchResX (which is reportedly still working on M1)

Answer (score 1):

For external displays, holding the Option key while selecting Scaled still brings up the list of resolutions. I don't think this has ever worked for the internal display.

Additional source: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-your-displays-resolution-mchl86d72b76/mac